# Auth0 and Vue: Error in render function: "InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Tags: vuejs2, auth0

guys, I'm going through the VueJS tutorial for Auth0, and am getting this error:

```
InvalidTokenError {message: "Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"}
message:"Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"
```

The tutorial is here:

https://auth0.com/blog/vuejs2-authentication-tutorial/

The error is happening right when the app is supposed to bring up the Auth0 Lock widget.

Thoughts?

Comment: I have the same issue, currently investigating if I can find the solution.

Answer (score 25):

Clear your browser's local storage cache.
e.g 
for Chrome, press F12 to go to developer window, Storage\Local Storage, right click and clear.
For IE, F12 to developer window. On 'Console' tab, run the command

```
localStorage.clear()
```

Comment: That is the weirdest bug I've ever seen, but doing your `localStorage.clear()` fixed it when Angular 4 was not letting me load the page! Thanks

Comment: Any reason why this happens?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. But please explain why this works?

Comment: You might have a token with same name but invalid payload in your local storage which the application was trying to read/decode but wasnt able to. Clearing the local storage removed all tokens and then you were able to create a new token with valid payload which your application was able to read/decode.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry I cannot comment on your question because my rank is too low. I had the same error coming up when I followed the react version of you tutorial.

The issue in my case was due to the fact that in the `auth.js` file, there is a function called `getTokenExpirationDate(encodedToken)`. Inside that function the line `const token = decode(encodedToken);` was the cause of the bug.

By investigating the value of encodedToken I found out that it's value was a string with the characters `'none'`, (not the value none itself!). This makes the encode function very unhappy.

If you go in the chrome developer tools, click on the Application tab, open the Local Storage option on the left hand side and select you site. You will be able to see all the key-value pairs stored in your local storage for your app. In my case the key `id_token` had the value `none`. If it's the case for you too, just delete that key/value pair from the local storage and the page should be able to load again.

Hope this helped and good luck!

**Edit**
By playing with local storage with chrome developer tools I realised the local storage can be a bit buggy. Sometimes I try to view the local storage but it doesn't appear. When that happens just try closing and reopening the tool.

Comment: Thanks, closing and reopening the console made the trick. (after clearing the localStorage). This remains a weird issue as my token in LS was perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

I also was running into this issue. I had one rule called 'auth0-authorization-extension' activated that triggered this error.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me. It is in typescript. You can remove (token: string) to (token) if not using TS

```
function parseJwt (token: string) {
    var base64Url = token.split('.')[0];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));

    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have token in another place, you can copy token in cookies.

1. you can find your token in Insomia software.
2. you can copy it
3. come back to browser and open inspect with F12
4. open cockies and paste token there